# How to display text in a span tag based on the value of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display text "USERNAME" in the span tag based on the value of input field.

If input field has any value I want to display the text "USERNAME" in the span tag. If input field has no value then I want the span tag to have no text inside it.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#username-input")
        .keydown(function () {
            function addRemoveUsername() {
                var inputChecker = document.getElementById("username-input");
                if (inputChecker.value == "") {
                    document.getElementById("name")
                        .innerHTML = "";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("name")
                        .innerHTML = "USERNAME";
                }
            }
            addRemoveUsername();
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="login-form">
    <span id="name"></span><br>
    <input id="username-input" type="text" placeholder="USERNAME">
</form>
```

Just how do I do it?

Comment: do you see any error in console

Comment: Even Ur code is working.. https://jsfiddle.net/nmLq0vjx/

Comment: If you're using JQuery, as hinted by your fiddle, $("name").text(myValue), sets the text content of the span of ID "name", and $("username-input").val() gets the value of the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.keyup` as below snippet.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#username-input").keyup(function() {
    var inputChecker = document.getElementById("username-input");
    //blank spaces will be trimmed before text from the input field
    if ($.trim(inputChecker.value) == "") {
      document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = ""; 
      inputChecker.value = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "USERNAME";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id ="login-form">
    <span id="name"></span><br>
    <input id="username-input" type="text" placeholder="USERNAME">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you mean?

```js
$(function () {
    $("#username-input")
        .keyup(function () {
           $('span#name').text($(this).val().length == 0 ? 'USERNAME' : '');
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="login-form">
    <span id="name">USERNAME</span><br>
    <input id="username-input" type="text" placeholder="USERNAME">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
<form id ="login-form">
<span id="name"></span><br>
<input id="username-input" type="text" placeholder="USERNAME" onkeyup='addRemoveUsername()'>
```

Javascript :

```
function addRemoveUsername () {
 var inputChecker = document.getElementById("username-input").value;
 if (inputChecker == "") {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = ""; 
 } else {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "USERNAME";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution and working JS bin link 
https://jsbin.com/perudafama/edit?html,console,output

```
$("#username-input").on('keydown', function(){
        var inputChecker = document.getElementById("username-input");
        if (inputChecker.value == "") {
            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = ""; 
        } else {
            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "USERNAME";
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

HTML

```
<span></span>
<input type=text>
```

The JS:

```
$("[type=text]").keyup(function(){

     $(this).val()==""?$("span").html(""):$("span").html("USERNAME");
})
```

Don't forget to include jQuery library.

Comment: It's good practice to use .text() rather than .html(), as it's slightly more efficient, and also adds an extra (thin) layer of sanitation.

Comment: That's true. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It should work

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#username-input').on('change paste keyup', function(){
        if($(this).val() == '')
        {
            $('#name').html('');
        }else{
            $('#name').html('USERNAME');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this has an accepted answer -it would be better if someone provided a better alternative than trying to fit the OP's requirement. A span is not an alternative to a label element. You are creating a form with an input and using a span a surrogate for the input label - this is not good. Use the correct tool for the job. Then you can alter the content of the label as required.

```
<form id ="login-form">
    <label for="username-input"></label>
    <input id="username-input" type="text" placeholder="USERNAME">
</form>
```

Then you need to consider whether you need the form at all - are you submitting it? the form has no action or method or submit button - which is all fine if you are doing via AJAX, but your input has no name - which again if you are doing via javascirpt / jquery - then you can get the value and submit via AJAX - but if you could do that then I assume that you have the skill to apply the solution to this rather simple problem.

Also not that the answers that suggest adding / swapping HTML in jQuery code are simply wrong - if you are doing that you need to be adding / swapping text (using the .text() method or .textContent if using vanilla javascript).

Also the idea of adding content to the dom based on the user input when it is only a single phrase (although you could obviously want to do more than just display the USERNAME text - but if that all you are doing then the better way is to have the content in there already and simply hide it or display it using CSS - either toggle a class to swap the display or using visibility:hidden (note that if you use display:none it will mess with your layout and move the input up into the space).

None of this is targetted to you as the OP - you are asking a question and trying to learn - this message is to the posters of the answers - all of whom rushed to answer a question and none of whom stopped to think if the question was correct and whether their answer would enhance the leaning of a new coder.

Comment: Your statements are correct and make a lot of sense. Thanks.